# Reading any type of file in C#

Tags: c#, file, directory, filestream

My program needs to read any type of file from a given directory path and it has to write that information into a byte array.

```
 string combine = Path.Combine(precombine, filename);
 string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(combine);
```

This way I can read a text file however I have to read all kind of files such as music or image and write them into a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
byte[] fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(combine);
```